# Linux Filesystem Overlay - what is workdir used for? (OverlayFS)

Tags: overlayfs

OverlayFS has a `workdir` option, beside two other directories `lowerdir` and `upperdir`, which needs to be an empty directory.

Unfortunately [the kernel documentation of overlayfs](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt) does not talk much about the purpose of this option.

> The "workdir" needs to be an empty directory on the same filesystem as upperdir.

For readonly overlays the `workdir` might be ommittet among the `upperdir`. This give me the clue that it has to do with writing the merged files.

Please explain what's happening in the `workdir` when files are written or changed in the merged directory. Why is the writable `upperdir` not enough?

Comment: My guess: When a lower file is to be modified, it is copied (a non-atomic operation) to workdir and then atomically moved into the right place in upper. Thus, other processes will either open the (complete) lower file or (after the switch) the complete upper file, never a halfway-done file.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> The workdir option is required, and used to prepare files before they
> are switched to the overlay destination in an atomic action (the
> workdir needs to be on the same filesystem as the upperdir).

Source: [http://windsock.io/the-overlay-filesystem/](https://web.archive.org/web/20220930060750/http://windsock.io/the-overlay-filesystem/)

I would hazard a guess that "the overlay destination" means `upperdir`.

So... certain files (maybe "whiteout" files?) are non-atomically created and configured in `workdir` and then atomically moved into `upperdir`.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score -4):

Because when you delete a file which is on lowerdir, this information will be stored in the workdir.

Comment: Hm, but when I delete files in the merged directory, the workdir remains empty but there are files shown in the _upperdir_ with a `c` flag (`c--------- 1 root root 0, 0 Nov 19 18:22 ivebeendeleted`) when they've been "overlay-deleted" from the lower dir. (The same file remains in the lowerdir of course.)

Comment: I think when you delete a file, a "whiteout" file is created and this is stored in the upperdir, not the workdir. The whiteout file is a character device (with "c" flag)